# Establish by year the most popular car brand

Tags: r, dplyr

Imagine a very big database (Cars) containing the car brand, year and sales for a certain country.

Ex (completly random): In a .csv file, we have:

```
carbrand - year - sales
toyota - 1950 - 3540
toyota - 1951 - 3433
toyota - 1952 - 3678
...
ford - 1950 - 4322
ford - 1951 - 2987
...
subaru - 1950 - 6544
subaru - 1951 - 5454
...
```

What I'm trying to do is to establish the most popular brand for each year. The output format itself is not very important here. Just searching for the idea.
Ex:

```
1950: subaru - 6544
1951: subaru - 5454
1952: toyota - 3678
```

What I can do so far is to rank them by the most sold:

```
Cars <- read_delim("file.csv",delim=" - ")
Cars %>% arrange(desc(sales))
```

```
subaru - 1950 - 6544
subaru - 1951 - 5454
ford - 1950 - 4322
toyota - 1952 - 3678
toyota - 1950 - 3540
toyota - 1951 - 3433
ford - 1951 - 2987
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example It is not clear to me of the dats you showed is tored in different columns or if this is oen concatenated column and you first want to extract the specific parts into their own columns.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(Cars)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(Cars, 20))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just group by `Year`, sort descending and keep the first row per group.

```
library(dplyr)

Cars %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  arrange(desc(Quant)) %>%
  slice(1)
## A tibble: 3 x 3
## Groups:   Year [3]
#  Car     Year Quant
#  <chr>  <dbl> <int>
#1 subaru  1950  6544
#2 subaru  1951  5454
#3 toyota  1952  3678
```

**Data**

```
cars <- "
Car - Year - Quant
subaru - 1950 - 6544
subaru - 1951 - 5454
ford - 1950 - 4322
toyota - 1952 - 3678
toyota - 1950 - 3540
toyota - 1951 - 3433
ford - 1951 - 2987"

tc <- textConnection(cars)
Cars <- read.delim(tc, sep = "-")
close(tc)
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you very much.